# Set NLSLANG without thousand seperator

Tags: oracle

I would like to change nls_numeric_characters so that I don't have any thousand character seperator and only comma as decimal seperator.

```
TO_CHAR(15000000.05,'99G990D00', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',''')
```

gives me the error "invalid NLS parameter string used in SQL function"

How do I do this?

Comment: Why not just leave the G out of the format model?

Comment: @AlexPoole honestly I found this example somewhere, tried modifying it and it didn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have no group separator defined. [From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/nlspg/setting-up-globalization-support-environment.html#GUID-F7477179-18DA-445A-AD07-05CD22EEC425) the `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` setting is "Any two valid numeric characters", so you can't only set one of them and leave the other null. (Using a null *character* is still using two chars, and doesn't do what you want, as @Matthew demonstrated).

If you don't want the group separator in your string, just omit it from your format model:

```
select to_char(15000000.05, '999999990D00', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=,.') from dual;

TO_CHAR(15000
-------------
  15000000,05
```

I've added more 9s to the start of the model as your original didn't have enough digit placeholders for the size of the value, so would have returned hashes instead of anything useful.

(The column width is the length of the format model plus an extra space to allow for a sign character, and the string is left-padded to that width - to keep right-alignment of multiple values. You can lose the padding by adding the FM modifier if you prefer.)

Answer (score 3):

I do not think you can use `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` to suppress the group separator.  That is what format models are for.  If you don't want group separators, don't ask for them in your format model.  All `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` will do is specify what the group separator should be, when it is asked for.

Even if you use `CHR(0)`, as in:

```
select TO_CHAR(15000000.05,'999G999G990D00', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ,' || chr(0))
from dual
```

> ```
> 15000000,05
> ```

The answer still gets chr(0)s embedded in it (which you can see if you wrap the expression in a `DUMP()` function., like this:

```
select DUMP(TO_CHAR(15000000.05,'999G999G990D00', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ,' || chr(0)))
from dual
```

> ```
> Typ=1 Len=15: 32,32,49,53,0,48,48,48,0,48,48,48,44,48,53
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If your application allow this, you can change get the wanted result by changing the `nls_territory`:

```
alter session set nls_territory='America';
select * from nls_session_parameters where parameter='NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS';
```

gives :

```
PARAMETER;VALUE 
-------------------------
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS;.,
```

but this :

```
alter session set nls_territory='France';
select * from nls_session_parameters where parameter='NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS';
```

gives :

```
PARAMETER;VALUE 
-------------------------
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS;,
```