# Convert number to varchar2 in PLSQL without thousand separator in PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, type-conversion

Is there a safe and fast way to convert a number to a varchar2 without having thousand separators (regardless of collation or other settings).

Examples:

```
/* Normal Collation */
1234.5 => '1234.5' (and not '1,234.5')
1.5 => '1.5'
/* Reverse Collation */
1234.5 => '1234,5' (and not '1.234,5')
1.5 => '1,5'
```

What I have so far is:

```
declare
  thousand_separator# varchar2(1);
begin
  thousand_separator# := nullif(substr(to_char(1000), 2, 1), 0);

  dbms_output.put_line(case when thousand_separator# is null then to_char(123456.123) else replace(to_char(123456.123), thousand_separator#) end);
end;
```

I was looking for something of the type `to_char(<number>, 'CORRECT_FORMAT')`, or similar (that won't add any leading or trailing zeros)

Comment: In your case expression `thousand_separator#` can't ever be null, since you assign it via `nvl()`. Why can't you just  use a format mask that doesn't include the group separator (e.g. '99999D99999' with enough nines either side of the decimal separator for the possible range of values you expect to see - [as here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54782823/266304))?

Comment: Are there values that don't display properly by default? The only thing I can immediately think of is - how should numbers below zero (e.g. 0.5) display?

Comment: @AlexPoole I mean to write `nullif` and not `nvl`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [the `TM` 'text minimum'](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-24E16D8D-25E4-4BD3-A38D-CE1399F2897C) format model:

> The text minimum number format model returns (in decimal output) the smallest number of characters possible.

although that is what you get by default is you use `to_char()` with no model anyway.

Demo with either decimal separator:

```
alter session set nls_numeric_characters = '.,';

with t (num) as (
  select 1234.5 from dual
  union all
  select 1.5 from dual
  union all
  select 0.5 from dual
  union all
  select 0 from dual
  union all
  select 5 from dual
)
select to_char(num, 'TM') as str
from t;

STR                                                             
----------------------------------------------------------------
1234.5
1.5
.5
0
5

begin
  dbms_output.put_line(to_char(123456.123));
end;
/

123456.123
```

```
alter session set nls_numeric_characters = ',.';

with t (num) as (
  select 1234.5 from dual
  union all
  select 1.5 from dual
  union all
  select 0.5 from dual
  union all
  select 0 from dual
  union all
  select 5 from dual
)
select to_char(num, 'TM') as str
from t;

STR                                                             
----------------------------------------------------------------
1234,5
1,5
,5
0
5

begin
  dbms_output.put_line(to_char(123456.123));
end;
/

123456,123
```

Comment: Was under the impression that `to_char` was dependent on collation and `nls_numeric_characters`. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#r17c1-t56), it says that the default is `TM9`, is there a difference between that and `TM`?

Comment: No, TM9 is just explicit - TM is shorthand for TM9 really. As distinct from TMe.